# Eclipse link jpa problem

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

With two users simultaneously using my simple app, I'm getting exception:

```
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, NAME, IMAGE FROM GameObjectTable ORDER BY ID ASC
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=GameObject sql="SELECT ID, NAME, IMAGE FROM GameObjectTable ORDER BY ID ASC")

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: There was In/Out error while sending to server
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:283)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:479)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:367)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:891)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:601)
... 116 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:26)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:121)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:507)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendSync(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1107)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:256)
... 121 more
```

Method cousing error is:

```
@Repository
public class GameObjectDao{
  @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
  protected EntityManager entityManager;
  @Transactional
  public List<String> getGameObjectNames() {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("select g.name from GameObject as g").getResultList();
 ...
}
```

}

Spring transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

What is wrong?

//EDIT

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect "/>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
```

In mysql error is different:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
... 69 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:1646)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:1622)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:891)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:601)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:529)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeCall(AbstractSession.java:914)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:205)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:191)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:262)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:618)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2537)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2496)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:455)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:997)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:675)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:958)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:432)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1021)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1225)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1181)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:453)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:669)
```

Comment: you connection-pool settings, if any?

Answer (score 1):

If the first exception translates to (as I'm guessing):

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
```

Then it is very likely not an EclipseLink issue but a PostgreSQL issue.

Set the following in `postgresql.conf` on the server and reload:

```
log_statement=all
log_min_error_statement=ERROR
log_min_messages=ERROR
log_connections=on
log_disconnections=on
```

Then check the server logs and update your question with any suspicious message (and the lines surrounding it).

Comment: I changed postgresql.conf and restart database server. Then I replicated error in my app, but nothing suspicious occurred in postgresql logs. Only information about queries, transactions - no errors.

Comment: I've just tested mysql -> in the same situation error, but on this database null pointer :/

Comment: Weird. What is the IMAGE field? A BLOB?

Comment: @Lob
    protected byte[] image;

Comment: It is probably something with transactions, when I disabled them, no exception here :/ But why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the database connection is being closed by the first request, and the second request retrieves the closed connection from the pool and fails.

What does your datasource definition look like?

Comment: I've just added beans definitions